# Como pegar a porcentagem de bateria?

Tags: android

Como pegar a porcentagem de bateria e informar num gráfico estilo bateria?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vou responder parcialmente a sua pergunta.

Para recuperar o nível da bateria, você precisa disparar um Intent-Filter para `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`. Abaixo, segue um exemplo de código que, também, programa um `BroadCastReceiver` para ser executado quando a Intent for disparada.

```
//Método responsável para descobrir o nível da bateria
private void batteryLevel(){
    //Cria o broadcastreceiver
    BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        //Método executado sempre que o broadcast for executado
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent  intent){             
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            //pega nível da bateria da intent
            int rawLevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);

            //pega o nível máximo da bateria
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
            int level = -1;

            if(rawLevel >= 0 && scale > 0){
            //faz o cálculo do percentual.
            level = (rawLevel *100)/scale;
            }
        }
    }
};

//Cria um intent filter para a classe BATTERY_CHANGED.
//Em BATTERY_CHANGED você tem acesso a outras informações sobre a bateria.
IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);;
registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
```

---

Fonte: [techne.cesar.org.br](http://techne.cesar.org.br/descobrindo-informacoes-de-bateria-dos-dispositivos-android/)
Sugestão de leitura: [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) (em Inglês)